# Shape of Dragon Crew capsule affecting ballistic descent?

Tags: spacex, dragon, dragon-v2

[image: The Dragon that Musk presented]\   I I don't think anyone has the seen the actual dimensions of dragon version 2, but assuming it is what SpaceX will be using to take people to space, I think it will have issues regarding stability during descent. At-least some amount of the cross section of the spacecraft appears to be squarish (shown in pink and blue) . This is probably a unintended consequence of having descent engines to the side ( which is now redundant since they aren't doing propulsive landing). This will affect both lift features, and also gyroscopic stabilization during ballistic descent, if at all possible, will be a lot harder because it would be harder to rotate around its principal axis, since the frame is not symmetric. Is this correct? Also the frame features intended for propulsive landing, like the big channels that leads to the nozzle (circled in green) will seriously affect the overall dynamics, especially during descent, especially since they don't seem to be symmetric.

Comment: What makes you think symmetry is critical @user2277550?

Comment: @GdD For soyuz for exaple, lift is critical during re-entry, and it has to be somewhat actively controlled (I am not sure about the control part). But anyway, if you don't have a somewhat stable shape, there is no way you can control lift right? For ballistic descent, drag about the principal axis would be higher without symmetry (not sure how serious this is) but it seems an un-necessary complication. Of course there are a lot of approximations that go on here, but SpaceX's design seems to be somewhat too problematic.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean when you talk about asymmetry here @user2277550, maybe a picture or two would help. If you mean the shape of the TPS itself then the asymmetry is an intended part of the design to give life and control to re-entry rather than a pure ballistic descent.

Comment: @GdD By ballistic descent, I am talking about how the whole craft is spun up for gyroscopic stabilization, during ballistic descent. I have added a picture.

Comment: @GdD A bit of asymmetry is present in both Apollo and Soyuz, but that is just a fin that changes lift when the overall structure is rolled. But I don't think there is any example of the overall frame being asymmetric.

Comment: @user2277550 here is the dimentions that you say  nobody have seen and more information about the dragon2 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_2

Comment: "the whole craft is" NOT "spun up for gyroscopic stabilization during ballistic descent"

Comment: @OrganicMarble Soyuz does that. It makes sense to have it as an extra safety option.

Comment: @trondhansen they have changed a lot from that. They said they are not doing propulsive landing, which most probably means they have removed the small legs at the bottom. I means accurate dimensions of each feature.

Comment: I have not been able to find a reference to Soyuz using spin stabilization during any reentry.

Comment: Downvoted till a reference is provided showing the spin stabilized Soyuz.

Comment: @OrganicMarble http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-l7MM9yoxII&t=14m10s There is a much better reference of the ROSCOSMOS chief explaining this after a 2008 ballistic descent. Not that I care much about an upvote.

Comment: I don't watch youtube videos. If you have a technical reference, [edit] it into your question. Or ignore me, that's your choice.

Comment: @OrganicMarble It is an ESA official video. Not a random one.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The first answer in this discussion page, of an article translated from Russian, after a 2008 ballistic descent. https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=11674.0

Comment: Your video describes a ballistic descent under no active control. The spacecraft spins randomly due to buffeting, canceling out the offset CoM that lets it provide lift when actively steered. A typical descent is actively steered with RCS to hold a desired angle of attack. See this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgTNzDCc0gk -- This is not 'spin stabilized,' just a natural roll that occurs without guidance.

Comment: @Saiboogu https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?topic=11674.0 “The descent along the ballistic  trajectory without the participation of lift is comparable with a falling stone, but if we permitted it to fall like a stone,  then the overload would reach a limit incompatible with human life. Therefore we constantly rotated the descent vehicle  around its axis, it achieved approximately one revolution after half a minute, what contributed (to transfer) the life-threatening ‘foot-head’ overload into the more acceptable ‘chest-spin’ overload due to the centrifugal  force,”

Comment: @Saiboogu The first answer in that discussion page. Well, regular roll error will obviously be there, because is is not in a potential minima along its body axis. But why would natural spin cancel out offset COM?

Comment: @user2277550 I'm assuming translation error. The trajectory is specified by the shape and angle of attack. A guided descent controls AoA to generate lift. An unguided descent has no control over roll, so it has no control over AoA. The random rolling action means that rather than holding a given AoA to generate lift, the AoA constantly rotates with the roll for an average result that matches the behavior of a capsule without offset CoM. Centrifugal force from rotation cannot remove or reduce the G loading from deceleration, so the quote cannot be accurate as presented.

Comment: @Saiboogu I don't think that is accurate. An unguided descent (in the case of Soyuz) has no fine control over roll. But it is almost easily possible to spin the spacecraft itself, upto a maximum value. One you do that, it seems obvious that  gyroscopic forces will offset COM to a certain extent, which will diminish G loads from deceleration. Hence I think the quote is accurate.

Answer (score 6):

1. The pink and blue sections are not square, they are cone sections.
2. There are 4 thruster units on the capsule, and they are arranged in a regular pattern. The capsule is symmetric.
3. I have seen no statement by SpaceX that they will use gyroscopic stabilization.

Here's a [diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5d/Dragon_V2_01.png) of the capsule showing that the capsule is symmetric:

[image: Crew Dragon]

During a ballistic descent, the capsule will fall heatshield-first, and the rest of the capsule including the thruster fairings is in the lee of the heatshield. Most of the ballistic descent will be at supersonic speeds, where the capsule is in the lee of a shockwave.

Without doing an aerodynamics analysis, I suspect it wouldn't be very difficult to spin the capsule.

The thrusters still serve a function: they are the abort system.

It seems to me that the channels leading to the thrusters would have a stabilizing effect: when the capsule goes off-axis it exposes one of the channels more to the airstream, creating more drag which pushes the capsule back, until all 4 channels have minimal exposure and the capsule is in equilibrium.

You want to avoid spinning the capsule, because it uses parachutes during the final stages of the descent. If the capsule would spin at that point, you'd tangle the parachutes.

Comment: Gyroscopic stabilization, at least with Soyuz, is done as a last ditch option to flatten the trajectory during ballistic descent. Ballistic descent itself is done when the spacecraft lift can't be actively controlled, i.e. as a extra safety measure. I am not sure why my question got so many negative votes.

Comment: @user2277550 I don't think it was clear to most responders that you are talking about emergency and last ditch measures, rather than a routine descent. Without that it could be seen as a "based on this one photo I'm goign to claim that a major company is being incredibly stupid" question which doesn't usually go down well.

Comment: @Hobbes The front view, IMHO, seems to be problematic. The black parts, when spun around the axis will make it difficult to control the lift. And the black part itself was mainly intended for propulsive landing which they are not using (I read). Of course they could have put it into a wind tunnel, tested it a lot, and put those values into the control system. But there seems to be too many superfluous things in the design itself.

Comment: @SteveLinton I would think that such emergency measures have a significant bearing on basic design.

Comment: @user2277550 sure, and on acceptance, I'm sure. Do you have any source for the idea that SpaceX will use the same emergency measures as Soyuz? In particular they may have alternatives to gyroscopic stabilization.

Comment: @SteveLinton I am not sure there are any other choices. Of course you could put a heavy gyroscope inside, the way ships do it, but I don't think it will be good enough especially with weight constraints. SpaceX has not talked about many such critical issues, and most people (IMHO) generally accept whatever SpaceX says as gospel.

Comment: @user2277550 Capsules roll naturally when not guided (ballistic descent). Stability is natural due to the shape, not gyroscopic.

Comment: Additional bit of info that seems lacking -- The 'black part' is the exhaust for the engines that are critical for launch escape. Propulsive landing was just an additional perk of their existence.